# How to create a regex expression with this pattern?

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Someone knows how can i make a regex of this pattern?

For my problem, an input example would be `ggggggg@aaaaa.com.br` and the expected output would be `gg***gg@aa***.com.br`.
As you can see, the letter before the @ will be only replaced with , if the string has more than 4 characters, following the pattern `gg**gg@`, and after the @ two letters followed by * up to the  end of the email provider.

Another example would be when there are 3 letters or less:

from `ggg@aaaaa.com` to `g*g@aa***.com`

I've tried to make this way, but it's still not working:

`regex = /(^.{2})(.*)(.{2})@(.{2})(?:(?=\.)(.*)|(\w+)(.*))/gm;`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have 2 separate problems -- string matching and string replacement. Can you make it more clear what you have for each?

Comment: I want to mask an email with the above pattern, with the regex i want to do regex replacement with js.

Comment: If you're working in any reasonable language, you should strongly consider writing string slicing code to do this transformation. Tricky regex-es and substitutions are among the most confusing and error prone bits of code in existence.  The people responsible for maintaining this thing (including your future self) will thank you.  nb: You could reasonably use capturing regexes to get the slices.

Answer (score 0):

When you put something in paranthesis in a regex (like for example: `s/\(.\)\1/\1/g` You can use \1 to \9 later on to match repeating patterns. Here's the regex I came up with that (mostly) fits the criteria:

`s/\(.\)\1..\1\1@\(.\)\2.*\.com\.br/\1\1**\1\1@\2\2***.com.br/g`.
I wasn't able to get it to automatically put in the exact number of stars at the end so that the character count still lines up with the original email, but hopefully it still helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can use capture groups and based on the number of characters in group 1 and group 2 you can compose a return string.

```
([^\s@]+)@([^\s@.]+)(\.[^\s@]+)
```

The pattern matches

- `([^\s@]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except `@` or a whitespace char
- `@` Match the `@`
- `([^\s@.]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except `.` `@` or a whitspace char
- `(\.[^\s@]+)` Capture **group 3**, match a single dot and the rest of the email address

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BrfXAV/1)

```js
const regex = /([^\s@]+)@([^\s@.]+)(\.[^\s@]+)/;
const strings = [
  "ggggggg@aaaaa.com.br",
  "abcdefghijklmnop@aaaaa.com.br",
  "abc@aaaaa.com",
  "gg@aaaaa.com",
  "g@aaaaa.com",
  "@aaaaa.com",
];

strings.forEach(s => {
  let res = s.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2, g3) => {
    let first = g1;
    if (g1.length === 3) {
      first = `*${g1.charAt(1)}*`
    }
    if (g1.length > 3) {
      first = `**${g1.slice(2, -2)}**`
    }
    return `${first}@${'*'.repeat(g2.length)}${g3}`
  });
  console.log(res);
})
```